# How do I call ForceClient.UserInfo() synchronously

Tags: rest-api, .net

I'm converting the data access layer of an old app from MySql to Salesforce using WinForms, DeveloperForce, Visual Studio 2015, .Net 4.6.1, C#.  This is my first real TPL/async/await project.

I'm stuck on how to call ForceClient.UserInfo synchronously.

Anyway, this works:

```
public ForceClient Connect(){
    if (_forceClient == null){
        _auth = new AuthenticationClient();
        _auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(...).Wait();
        _forceClient = new ForceClient(_auth.InstanceUrl, _auth.AccessToken, _auth.ApiVersion);
    }
    return _forceClient;
}
...
private async Task<int> GetSomeData(){
    var response = await Force.Connect().QueryAsync<dynamic>("SELECT...").ConfigureAwait(false);
    //load data to local storage
    return response.Count
}
```

So far so good - The connect() blocks the first time until it connects, then I send all my queries at once and load them in pseudo parallel as the results are returned. Yay.  Now I want to add a synchronous call to ForceClient.UserInfo() toward the end of the connect method.

This works asyncronously:

```
userInfo = await _forceClient.UserInfo<UserInfo>(UserInfoEndpointUrl);
```

But all my attempts to call it synchronously have failed.  I've tried .Wait(), .RunSynchronously(), Task.WaitAll, Task.WaitAny, ConfigureAwait(false),... Most things I try end up causing the call to hang indefinitely (thread deadlock)

Help?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there an Exception occurring? Possibly based on the `UserInfoEndpointUrl` being null, empty, or not a well formed Uri? See [UserInfo](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/5bec98ead34b291a82478314e795000e8d567858/src/ForceToolkitForNET/ForceClient.cs#L189)

Comment: From the examples you should be passing the AuthenticationClient.Id as the UserInfoEndpointUrl.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger - In a small test program, I am able to get this to work asynch:

     userInfo = await _forceClient.UserInfo<UserInfo>("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo");


but not

      userInfo = await _forceClient.UserInfo<UserInfo>(auth.id);

I think the real problem I struggling with is trying to call it with the .configureAwait(false).  I can't seem to avoid a threading deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

*Update based on comments.*

You need to use `Task.ConfigureAwait(false);` to prevent blocking the UI thread context.

See [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

---

I made the call synchronously using the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            MainAsync(args);
        }).Wait();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
            auth.UsernamePasswordAsync("ConsumerName", "ClientSecret", "user@example.com", "password goes here").Wait();

            var forceClient = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);

            // Without the Thread.Sleep above the application will often close before the result comes back.
            //var userInfo = await forceClient.UserInfo<UserInfo>(auth.Id);
            //Console.WriteLine(userInfo.FirstName);

            var task = forceClient.UserInfo<UserInfo>(auth.Id);
            task.Wait();
            var userInfo2 = task.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(userInfo2.FirstName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

If I made the call asynchronously and didn't have the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` the application would close before the UserInfo came back.

Note that the usage of `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` isn't ideal as an exception within the Task will be wrapped in an AggregateException.

See also:

- [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/54026)
- [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: I can make something like the above work in a console app, but not in my winforms app.  The calls like: var response = await Force.Connect().QueryAsync<dynamic>(soql) were also hanging until I added the .ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @Jeff Good to  know. Sounds like the deadlock occured on the UI thread when it blocked on the Task.